# Build x264 with error: signal.h not found

Tags: x264

When I build x264 using the build script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/Local/Android/sdk/android-ndk-r16b

PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-26/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
PREFIX=./android/arm

function build_one
{
 ./configure \
 --prefix=$PREFIX \
 --enable-static \
--enable-pic \
 --host=arm-linux \
 --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
 --sysroot=$PLATFORM

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_one

echo Android ARM builds finished
```

But i always got an error:

```
x264.c:40:20: fatal error: signal.h: No such file or directory
#include <signal.h>
                ^
```

compilation terminated.
: recipe for target 'x264.o' failed
make: *** [x264.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

One change of android-ndk-r16b is that [The deprecated headers have been removed. Unified Headers are now simply "The Headers". For migration tips, see Unified Headers Migration Notes.](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html)

So signal.h no longer exist in android-ndk-r16b. You can use lower version NDK, for example android-ndk-r15c.